# selecting rows with one same and one different column

Tags: sql, northwind

I am trying to list the Company Name of all **U.S.-based customers** who are **NOT located in the same state** (or region) as any of the employees.
It should **return 10 rows**. I have used the following query for this

```
SELECT Customers.CompanyName
FROM Customers
WHERE Customers.Country='USA'
  AND Customers.Region IN
    (SELECT Customers.Region
     FROM Customers
     GROUP BY Customers.Region HAVING COUNT(Customers.Region)=1);
```

but it returns only 6.

The database is **northwind**.
**Company name

---

```
here is the output
Old World Delicatessen
Let's Stop N Shop
Save-a-lot Markets
The Cracker Box
Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery
Split Rail Beer & Ale**
```

Comment: Can you put condition "where Customers.Country='USA'" after your subquery ends

Comment: can you show the required output

Comment: Some sample input and output would be very helpful.  It is not immediately clear what the query is supposed to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```sql
SELECT CompanyName
  FROM Customers
 WHERE Country='USA' AND 
       Region NOT IN
           (SELECT DISTINCT Region
              FROM Employees 
             WHERE Region IS NOT NULL);
```

Output

```
CompanyName
----------------------------------------
Great Lakes Food Market
Hungry Coyote Import Store
Let's Stop N Shop
Lonesome Pine Restaurant
Old World Delicatessen
Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery
Save-a-lot Markets
Split Rail Beer & Ale
The Big Cheese
The Cracker Box

(10 row(s) affected)
```

In your your question you said that you need *Company Name of all U.S.-based customers who are NOT located in the same state (or region) as **any of the employees**.* But in your query you were trying to get regions from **Customers** table instead.

**UPDATE**: I believe that you know that but just in case:

The explicit check for `NULL` values in the subquery (`WHERE Region IS NOT NULL`) is **crucial**. Without it the query will run successfully but won't return any rows.

```sql
SELECT CompanyName
  FROM Customers
 WHERE Country='USA' AND 
       Region NOT IN
           (SELECT DISTINCT Region
              FROM Employees);
```

Output:

```
CompanyName
----------------------------------------

(0 row(s) affected)
```

I guess that exercise that you were trying to accomplish was meant to make sure that you know about NULLs in subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Your query does not check `Employees` table at all! Check out that:

```
SELECT Customers.CompanyName, customers.Region
FROM Customers
WHERE Customers.Country='USA'
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Employees WHERE Employees.Region = Customers.Region)
```

or

```
SELECT Customers.CompanyName, customers.Region
FROM Customers
WHERE Customers.Country='USA'
AND  Customers.Region NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Employees.Region FROM Employees WHERE Employees.Region IS NOT NULL)
```

Both queries return:

```
Great Lakes Food Market         OR
Hungry Coyote Import Store      OR
Let's Stop N Shop               CA
Lonesome Pine Restaurant        OR
Old World Delicatessen          AK
Rattlesnake Canyon Grocery      NM
Save-a-lot Markets              ID
Split Rail Beer & Ale           WY
The Big Cheese                  OR
The Cracker Box                 MT
```